# How can I save only certain pages in SetAPDF-Formfiller

Tags: setapdf

I have 3 page PDF form which I fill with a SetaPDF formfiller. The values are taken from a database and based on some values 2nd or 3rd page of the document should be "disabled" in some cases thus  not needed in resulting filled document.

How can I make SetaPDF to save only certain pages?

https://manuals.setasign.com/api-reference/setapdf/c/SetaPDF.Core.Document#method_save
does not accept any parameters that define page numbers I want to have in resulting document.

UPD: https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-core-manual/pages/#index-5
Delete pages method could help me to get the expected result however I cannot make it work.

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question? As you write "disabled", wouldn't it make sense to [flatten](https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-formfiller-manual/flatten-or-delete-fields/#index-2) or make the fields [readonly](https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-formfiller-manual/field-types/#index-2-2) then?

Comment: Sure here it is https://www.upload.ee/files/14249743/701201_20220620_175952.pdf.html  What I need is when nothing on second page is checked do NOT include it to the resulting  PDF. The same for the tird page: when nothing checked do nOT include. How to tell SetaPDF to save only certain pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with only the [SetaPDF-FormFiller](https://www.setasign.com/formfiller) component is only possible if you have control about the original document and if you flatten all form fields after filling them!

It will look like following:

```
<?php

require_once 'library/SetaPDF/Autoload.php';

$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_File('result.pdf');
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename('701201_20220620_175952.pdf', $writer);

$formFiller = new SetaPDF_FormFiller($document);
$fields = $formFiller->getFields();
// ...fill fields
$fields->flatten();

$pages = $document->getCatalog()->getPages();
$pages->deletePage(3);
$pages->deletePage(2);

$document->save(false)->finish();
```

**ATTENTION**: Use this method with care! If you e.g. do not flatten the fields, internally all other form fields and their related pages will be kept internally because they are still referenced. The resulting document may look good but its internal structure would be messed.

If you want to keep the form fields and you don't want to care about the internal structure yourself you have to go with the [SetaPDF-Merger](https://www.setasign.com/merger) component. It will keep the internal structure of the PDF document intact and clean:

```
<?php

require_once 'library/SetaPDF/Autoload.php';

$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_File('result.pdf');
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename('701201_20220620_175952.pdf');

$formFiller = new SetaPDF_FormFiller($document);
$fields = $formFiller->getFields();
//...fill fields

$merger = new SetaPDF_Merger();
$merger->addDocument($document, 1); // only page 1
$merger->merge();

$resDocument = $merger->getDocument();
$resDocument->setWriter($writer);
$resDocument->save()->finish();
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I wish we had this explanation and example in SetaPDF documentation ;)